# CMake configuration specific library name when using multi-config generators

Tags: cmake

Running `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` on

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test CXX)
add_library(MyLib SHARED foo.cpp)
install(TARGETS MyLib DESTINATION $ENV{TEMP})
```

generates a project with several configurations (`Release`, `Debug`, ...) which can then be built with Visual Studio.

**The problem:** When installing the library (i.e. building the generated project named `INSTALL`), a `Debug` build will happily overwrite a `Release` build and vice versa.

**I am looking for** a means to create a different library name for each configuration, e.g. a `MyLib` for the release build and `MyLibd` for a debug build.

**What I have tried:** When using a single-config generator, I would have queried `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and provided a different name for the library for each configuration. However `"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` is a multi-config generator and thus I cannot apply such a technique.

I have read about [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) but all examples show only generator expressions applied to input arguments, such as input files or directories. And indeed, something like

```
add_library(MyLib$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d> SHARED foo.cpp)
```

will only produce nasty CMake error messages and does not yield the desired effect of having the library name depend on the configuration.

I could of course create a custom command which renames the file while installing, but in my understanding of CMake having "batteries included", there must be a simpler way. Generator expressions looked very promising, but it seems that doesn't work the way I have tried.

**Question:** How can I make the name of the library depend on the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assign [DEBUG_POSTFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/CONFIG_POSTFIX.html) property of the library target for have different postfix for debug builds.

Or you may do that for all targets by assigning [CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")
#... Create a library after the setting the postfix.
add_library(MyLib SHARED foo.cpp)
```

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CONFIG_POSTFIX "d")` didn't have any effect.  `set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")` works. Following the link you provided, I saw that the "all targets" setting should be `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX`. I.e. in my case: `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")`. Both do exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, I meant DEBUG instead of CONFIG. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

@Tsyvarev's hint on setting a property of the library target led to yet another solution: there is a target property [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) and this does allow the use of generator expressions.

So, one can write

```cmake
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "MyLib$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>")
```

Comment: I posted this answer because it allows a freely configurable library name as I have originally asked for. However, @Tsyvarev's answer has some other advantages: it is syntactically simpler, it is easier to see the intent, which is indeed only to add a suffix to the name, and one has the possibility to add a suffix for all targets. Therefore Tsyvarev's answer is the accepted answer.